# How to GROUP BY and LIMIT N results from one field?

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

In MySQL I have articles. Each article has category. I want get last N articles from each category ordered by date. How to do that in SQL? Also interested how to convert it to Yii2 Active Query.

Example: 10 articles, 3 categories. Category `A` has 2 articles, category `B` has 3 articles, category `C` has 5 articles.

With query like

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
GROUP BY 'category'
LIMIT 2
ORDER BY 'date'
```

I have to get 2 articles from `A`, 2 last articles from `B` and 2 last articles from `C`

Comment: That group by is invalid. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is:

```
select a.*
from articles a
where a.ctime >= coalesce((select a2.ctime
                           from articles a2
                           where a2.category = a.category
                           order by a2.ctime desc
                           limit 1, 1
                          ), a.ctime
                         );
```

MysQL does not allow `in` with correlated subqueries with `limit`.  Not sure why, but it does work for comparison operators.

Comment: Works almost perfect! The problem is if I have category only with 1 article, sql results will not print it.

Comment: @sirjay . . . Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use subqueries. The nested SELECT statement will fetch article ids grouped by a1 articles category, ordered by date and limited to 2.

```
SELECT * FROM articles a1
WHERE a1.id IN 
  (SELECT a2.id FROM articles a2 
   WHERE a1.category = a2.category 
   ORDER BY ctime desc LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY a1.category, a1.ctime;
```

Note:
this code won't work on older versions of MySQL. It will work on Oracle though.

Comment: It says an error that I can not use `IN` in my mysql version. So I changed to `SELECT * FROM article as a1 INNER JOIN (SELECT id, category FROM article ORDER BY created desc LIMIT 2) as a2 ON a1.category = a2.category ORDER BY a1.category, a1.created`, but it prints all results, so limit not works

Comment: @sirjay put limit outside the sub query

Comment: If I put, it will print 2 results only. But it must be 6 results (because 3 categories and I need 2 results from each category, so 2*3=6).

Comment: do check your execution plan once for this correlated subquery, it could become performance bottle neck with large number of records in the table

Answer (score -1):

Try this. it's the best example.

```
--(FOR MSSQL)
    select emp_no , sum(salary_amount) from emp_salary
    Group by emp_no 
    ORDER BY emp_no 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS       -- Skip first 5 
    FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY; -- limit to retrieve next 10 row after skip

--(For MYSQL)
    select emp_no , sum(salary_amount) from emp_salary
    Group by emp_no 
    ORDER BY emp_no 
    limit 0, 2
```